# Creating a new remote branch?

Tags: git

Quick sanity check - I wanted to create a new remote branch for myself. I want to do the following:

```
git clone git@github.com:orange/orange.git
git branch foo
git checkout foo
git push foo foo
```

I'd like to simply clone master, create a new branch named "foo" (using what was in master), then push it to a remote repo called "foo". Does the above do that? The last line seems a little weird, in that I'm naming "foo" twice.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are confused by the term "remote."  A remote is a repository that exists somewhere else.  A remote repository has branches; these are called "remote branches."  If your goal is to push your local `foo` branch to the repository that you just cloned then:

```
git push origin foo
```

When you `git clone`, Git creates a remote called `origin`.  So this is the remote you want to push to.  Your `git push` line assumes that there is a remote called `foo`.  If you have not explicitly created one, then it doesn't exist.

Comment: Huh I'm probably mixing terminology up then - I'm using github, and I see under my project a list of "branches". Each one has its own name. I do not have a remote named foo, I believe. All I want to do is create a new branch, then push it remotely so I see it under the branches list.

Comment: @user291701 I think I updated my answer since you read it, try refreshing.  :)